# Baffling Safari Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, safari

My code below works in firefox perfectly..but not in Safari. When I use the Safari debug it simply says there is a parse error, just after the first opening curly bracket {

```
function setVals4(class,val) 
{
    var array = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

    for (var g = 0; g < array.length; g++)
    {
        sel = array[g]
        //sel = document.myform.sel[g];

        for (i=0; i<sel.options.length; i++) 
        {
            //alert(sel.options[i].value)

            if (sel.className == class) 
            {
                if (sel.options[i].value == val) 
                {
                    sel.selectedIndex = i;
                }
            }       
        }       
    }
}
```

Can anyone figure out why? Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class` is a reserved word in JavaScript, even though it isn't used for anything (it's listed as a "future reserved word" in the [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)). If you change your parameter name to `clazz` (which is the usual thing) or `foo` or something, that should sort it out.

(There's also a missing semicolon after `sel = array[g]`, but that's okay, the language allows [semicolon insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons) at that point. Still, best to include them, especially if you ever want to [minify](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)/[pack](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)/[compress](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) your code down-the-line.)